# Virus database main.cvd uncompression

Tags: database, virus-scanning, virus-definitions

In my previous question ([Hexadecimal virus signatures database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965257/hexadecimal-virus-signatures-database)), I asked where I can get a hex virus signature database, and the answer was: ClamAV. So I downloaded the "main.cvd" database and was told that it was a compressed tar file. I have two questions to ask:

1. are the signatures in hex format (of course when uncompressed)?
2. how do I uncompress the "main.cvd" file to view its contents, do i just rename it to main.tar and then uncompress it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do It by using a text editor and removing the first 512 bytes. Then renamed the file extension to .tar.gz and opened it using winrar

Comment: Thank you. Finally I was able to extract main.cvd database file. I renamed to .gz and extracted with 7zip.... :)

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
dd if=main.cvd of=clamav_main.tar.gz skip=1 bs=512
tar zxvf clamav_main.tar.gz
chmod 700 *
```

Comment: is there a windows equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this one-line set of commands to work nicely:

```
xxd -ps -s 512 <CVD-FILE> | xxd -r -ps | tar -zx
```